# Can't resolve method addModifiers in javapoet

Tags: android, annotations, preprocessor, javapoet

I am generating a class using annotation processor in Android. For generating classes, I am using javapoet and it works fine when I use  it in java project but in Android I can't access `addModifiers` method on `TypeSpec`

```
 TypeSpec clz = TypeSpec.classBuilder("MyClass")
            .addModifiers(Modifier.PRIVATE)
            .build();
```

I have imported `javax.lang.model.element.Modifier` but still it says can't resolve method addModifiers, `Modifier` parameter of same method in source code is colored red and hovering cursor over it shows`can't resolve symbol modifier` message. Any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Modifier` enum isn’t available in Android’s class library. You’ll need to build with a Java SDK instead of the Android SDK.

Comment: Can I do that while writing java module in android studio?